# How to Show product review form in popup Magento2

Tags: magento2, popup, modal-popup, product-review

I searched a lot to find solution for this problem and seems that many of them are searching for a solution. Finally I did it with a simple workaround it will be helpful to someone.I don't know whether there is a perfect solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in your phtml file

```
<div id="review-mpdal" style="display: none"> 
            <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Review\Block\Form")->setTemplate("Magento_Review::form.phtml")->toHtml(); ?> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'],function($, modal) {
        'use strict';
        var options = {
            'type': 'popup',
            'title': '',
            'modalClass': 'review_form_modal',
            'responsive': true,
            'innerScroll': true,
            'buttons': [{
                text: $.mage.__('Back'),
                class: 'back_button_class',
                click: function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                    // any javascript coode
                }
            }]
        };

        var popup = modal(options, $('#review-mpdal'));
        $(".add").on('click',function(){
            $("#review-mpdal").modal("openModal");
        });

       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: in what phtml file?